# My pyautogui isn't installed in the right place

Tags: python, pyautogui

So I got PyAutoGui installed but I don't think its in the right place or something (I think the python interpreter is different from where its installed cuz when i try this:
import time

```
import time 

import pyautogui

time.sleep(30)
pyautogui.press('5')
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\censored.DESKTOP-E11NU1G\PycharmProjects\pressing a button\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

and I'm sure I got PyAutoGui installed cause when I put pip install PyAutoGui into my terminal it gives me a bunch of stuff that boils down to that I already have it installed.

Don't know if this helps but when I do:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\censored.DESKTOP-E11NU1G\PycharmProjects\pressing a button\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

I've just recently picked up learning python so it could just be a pretty obvious beginner mistake
thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating and activating a virtual environment before pip or pip3 installing pyautogui? (Also try upgrading pip with the command: pip install --upgrade pip)

On Mac (create virtual environment) Command: Python3 -m venv env (activate virtual environment) Command: source env/bin/activate.

On Windows (create virtual environment) Command: Python3 -m venv env (activate virtual environment) Command: env\Scripts\activate.

Comment: tried it and it gave me this : Program 'python3.exe' failed to run: The system cannot find the path specifiedAt line:1 char:1
+ Python3 -m venv env 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1      
+ Python3 -m venv env
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Comment: can you share the error from the terminal and or the code/codebase you are working with?

Comment: didnt i just do that? could you maybe elobarate sorry im stupid

Answer (score 0):

Some code-level quick fix I think you can try is to find out the path where the `pyautogui` package you installed actually resides and add the parent directory to `sys.path` variable.

Please let me detail based on my case.  When I install `pyautogui` via pip, I find the package is installed in below path:

```bash
D:\\Python\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyautogui
```

And when I import `sys` module and print `sys.path` variable there, the result is as follows:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)

>>> '[D:\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip', 'D:\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs', 'D:\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'D:\\Python\\Python310', 'D:\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
```

You can see that among the paths above **D:\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages** is found, where `pyautogui` installed above resides.  This is the prerequisite for your python interpreter to work in your code with `pyautogui` you installed, as the interpreter tries to find modules to import from the paths in `sys.path`.

There is better way for you, but with limited knowledge on your environment, I recommend you to try:

1. Specify the parent directory where `pyautogui` is located.
2. Manually add the path to `sys.path`: Add a line `sys.path.append(<your_path_of_parent_dir_for_pyautogui>)` in your code.

Let me suppose that you find your pyautogui directory at below path for example:

```bash
C:\\Users\\censored.DESKTOP-E11NU1G\\blahblah\\anywhere\\pyautogui
```

Then fix for your code could look like kind of:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\censored.DESKTOP-E11NU1G\\blahblah\\anywhere")

import time 

import pyautogui


time.sleep(30)
pyautogui.press('5')
```

Even though this might work for you it is not a good solution as you need to add additional unnecessary lines.  You wrote that you did `pip install pyautogui` from terminal.  What is the terminal you mean here?  My guess is that you triggered command prompt of Windows or so and typed `pip install pyautogui` there.  If this is the case, please try installing same package but by the way PyCharm IDE supports.  I believe it would support installing packages by specifying a python environment you want.  I wonder whether [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/guide/python/tutorials/getting-started-pycharm/installing-and-managing-python-packages/) might help you to try.